# Creating a Webpack Bundled Library with Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to build a library of typescript components that will be consumed by another library that is also typescript based.  We are currently using webpack to accomplish our bundling, with ts-loader as the loader to consume the TS files.

I'm unsure of how to generate the .d.ts files for the example library below.  Typescript does build the .d.ts files (with `declaration` set to true) but it is one file per module where I need one .d.ts file that can be used by consumers.

https://github.com/raybooysen/typescript-webpack-example

So my question is, is there a canonical example of how to accomplish this?  Is there a way that typescript consumers can import these .d.ts files correctly?  At the moment there seems to be very little documentation and examples on the net and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you looked into using grunt or gulp and using the `tsc --declaration` command or a post build command if you are using VS?

Comment: We use ts-loader which runs the ts compiler using the tsconfig.json file which has declaration set to true.  However, this generates one d.ts file PER module.  If this is ok, which it feels not, then how can this be consumed by a consuming project that is also typescript based.

Comment: @RayBooysen how did you solve it in the end? Would be helpful to know your final solution.

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev Apologies, just added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually opened an issue on the Typescript Github page and they have confirmed this is not possible:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8372#issuecomment-217219512

Comment: it is not possible out of the box with typescript, however dts-bundle does the job

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, is there a canonical example of how to accomplish this? Is there a way that typescript consumers can import these .d.ts files correctly

You generally do not want to use the *bundle* as a module consumer. That is a job of the person who uses the library as a final website artifact. This means you only have `foo.ts`/`foo.js` next to each other in your node module deployed artifacts. These can be consumed as it is with the TypeScript compiler.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Comment: Unsure what you mean by "You generally do not want to use the bundle as a module consumer"  

If not, what do I use?  I can't justify using the raw source from a module as a consumer as the library may have dependencies I don't want to handle.  For example, a library may use LESS/SASS files, that I don't want to have to compile.

Comment: All these *css* style files should become a part of the final consumers project and they get to choose how they bundle it (single file or split etc)

Comment: That's not what I meant. If I'm a library builder, I may use a lot of technologies that need processing, like SASS. This should not be the responsibility of the library consumer as they won't want to take on the burden of having to own this processing. That means the library developer needs to output something that is plain JS and CSS , not TS and SASS.

Answer (score 0):

[dts-bundle](https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle) works like a charm for this purpose.

Here is an example of how to set it up as a Webpack plugin:
[Typings in one bundle](https://medium.com/@vladimirtolstikov/how-to-merge-d-ts-typings-with-dts-bundle-and-webpack-e8903d699576)